# Is there anything wrong with this SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Folowing is the query returning zero rows, actually it shouldn't:

```
SELECT distinct(usr.user_id)
FROM
    OCN.users AS usr,
    OCN.users_groups_subscribe AS usr_grp,
    OCN.tests_users AS test_usr
WHERE
    usr.user_id=usr_grp.subscribe_user_id AND
    usr.user_id=test_usr.test_user_user_id AND
    test_user_test_id=116 AND
    (usr.user_first_name LIKE '%ajay%' OR usr.user_last_name LIKE '%ajay%')
ORDER BY usr.user_first_name, usr.user_last_name
```

Comment: What data do you have?

Comment: The query looks like correct. But without table structure and data.. how can test? may be left/right join makes the issue

Comment: It would be useful if you put your table structure into a SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: can you give sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the magic for me:

```
SELECT distinct usr.user_id 
FROM OCN.users AS usr
    left join OCN.users_groups_subscribe AS usr_grp on usr_grp.subscribe_user_id = usr.user_id
    left join OCN.tests_users AS test_usr on test_usr.test_user_user_id = usr.user_id
WHERE
    test_usr.test_user_test_id=116 AND
    (usr.user_first_name LIKE '%pramod%' OR usr.user_last_name LIKE '%pramod%')
ORDER BY usr.user_first_name, usr.user_last_name
```

Answer (score 4):

The only problem that could be is `test_user_test_id`.  I want to say it's probably `test_user.test_user_test_id` based on your other column `test_user.test_user_user_id`.

Try:

```
SELECT distinct(usr.user_id)
FROM
    OCN.users AS usr,
    OCN.users_groups_subscribe AS usr_grp,
    OCN.tests_users AS test_usr
WHERE
    usr.user_id=usr_grp.subscribe_user_id AND
    usr.user_id=test_usr.test_user_user_id AND
    test_usr.test_user_test_id=116 AND
    (usr.user_first_name LIKE '%ajay%' OR usr.user_last_name LIKE '%ajay%')
ORDER BY usr.user_first_name, usr.user_last_name
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use proper ANSI join syntax:

```
SELECT distinct usr.user_id
FROM OCN.users AS usr
    inner join OCN.users_groups_subscribe AS usr_grp on usr_grp.subscribe_user_id = usr.user_id
    inner join OCN.tests_users AS test_usr on test_usr.test_user_user_id = usr.user_id
WHERE
    test_usr.test_user_test_id=116 AND
    (usr.user_first_name LIKE '%ajay%' OR usr.user_last_name LIKE '%ajay%')
ORDER BY usr.user_first_name, usr.user_last_name
```

Now try to comment your joins one by one (together with corresponding columns) and see why you don't get any rows, like

```
SELECT distinct usr.user_id
FROM OCN.users AS usr
    --inner join OCN.users_groups_subscribe AS usr_grp on usr_grp.subscribe_user_id = usr.user_id
    inner join OCN.tests_users AS test_usr on test_usr.test_user_user_id = usr.user_id
WHERE
    test_usr.test_user_test_id=116 AND
    (usr.user_first_name LIKE '%ajay%' OR usr.user_last_name LIKE '%ajay%')
ORDER BY usr.user_first_name, usr.user_last_name
```